# Unable to plot 4 histograms of iris dataset features using matplotlib

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

using the iris dataset

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib
from sklearn import datasets
iris= datasets.load_iris()

x_index = 3
colors = ['blue', 'red', 'green']

for label, color in zip(range(len(iris.target_names)), colors):
    plt.hist(iris.data[iris.target==label, x_index], 
                     label=iris.target_names[label],
                                        color=color)

plt.xlabel(iris.feature_names[x_index])
plt.legend(loc='upper right')
plt.show()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qs1jn.png)

This code is plotting only one histogram with sepal length (image attached) as the x-axis.
To plot other features of iris dataset in a similar manner, I have to change the x_index to 1,2 and 3 (manually) and run this bit of code again.

To plot all four histograms simultaneously, I tried the following code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib
from sklearn import datasets
iris= datasets.load_iris()

fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows= 2, ncols=2)
colors= ['blue', 'red', 'green', 'black']

x_index= 0

for ax in axes.flat:
    for label, color in zip(range(len(iris.target_names)), colors):
        ax= plt.hist(iris.data[iris.target==label, x_index], label=             
                            iris.target_names[label], color=color)
        plt.xlabel(iris.feature_names[x_index])  
        plt.legend(loc='upper right')
        x_index+=1

plt.show()
```

This code gives me the following error:

IndexError: index 4 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 4

Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two issues:

1. `ax` is the name of the current axes in the loop. You should not redefine but instead *use* it as this is the axes you want to plot to. Replace `ax = plt.hist` by `ax.hist`.
2. `x_index+=1` needs to be in the outer loop, not in the inner loop. Otherwise it will increment up to 11 instead of 3. Better get rid of it entirely and use a normal loop variable.

Complete code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn import datasets
iris= datasets.load_iris()

fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows= 2, ncols=2)
colors= ['blue', 'red', 'green']

for i, ax in enumerate(axes.flat):
    for label, color in zip(range(len(iris.target_names)), colors):
        ax.hist(iris.data[iris.target==label, i], label=             
                            iris.target_names[label], color=color)
        ax.set_xlabel(iris.feature_names[i])  
        ax.legend(loc='upper right')


plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: the colors are for the labels- ['setosa', 'versicolor', 'virginica']. I need each histogram to plot each feature of the iris dataset and segregate each label by color. That is why I have three colors.

Comment: Well, how could anyone know, without you showing a [mcve] of the issue? What do you expect as an answer?

Comment: I have edited the question to shed more clarity on my doubt. Any advice from your end would be great. Thanks

Comment: Ok, now that we have a [mcve] available, it's rather straight forward to solve. See updated answer.

Comment: Thank you. This is very helpful